# How can I change the cmd font and font size with a command?

Tags: command-line, batch, batch-file, cmd.exe

Is there any way to change cmd font and font size with a command?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

download BG library for changing font size...

https://github.com/carlos-montiers/consolesoft-mirror/releases/download/20180921/bg39.zip

i'm using v3.9 for it. have fun!

how to use;

```
BG.EXE is a tool for print text color in cmd.exe. It accepts regular expressions for print ascii characters. It also have useful functions.


Notice: This version fixes a problem happened on windows 7 sp1 with the function font.


::::: Parameters :::::


Kbd
::Wait until you press any key, and returns the ascii code.
::If an extended key was pressed, returns the second code plus 256. Example. If you pressed the up arrow (224, 72) returns 327 (72+256).


LastKbd
::If any key was pressed, returns the ascii code, else return 0.
::If the key pressed is extended, it returns the second code plus 256. Example. If you pressed the up arrow (224, 72) returns 327 (72+256).


Mouse
::Wait until you press primary button into console area.
::When you press a valid button of mouse print: rowNumber colNumber (both 0 index based).
::Also, is returned a number, where you can get the same info:
::Set /A "mouseRow=%ErrorLevel% >> 0x10 , mouseCol=%ErrorLevel% & 0xFFFF"


DateTime
::Print eight numbers, separated by a space, that corresponds to the current:
::DayOfWeek Year Month Day Hour Minute Second Milliseconds
::
::DayOfWeek value is from 0 to 6. 0 is Sunday, 1 is Monday, ..., 6 is Saturday
::Year value is from 1601 to 30827
::Month value is from 1 to 12
::Day value is from 1 to 31
::Hour value is from 0 to 23
::Minute value is from 0 to 59
::Second value is from 0 to 59
::Milliseconds value is from 0 to 999


Cursor 0 | 1 | 25 | 50 | 100
::hide or show cursor of keyboard or change the size.
::0 hide
::1 show
::25 small size
::50 medium size
::100 large size


Font 0 | 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 | 5 | 6 | 7 | 8 | 9
::change the size of font to terminal font according this next table:
:: index    size
:: 0        4x6
:: 1        6x8
:: 2        8x8
:: 3        16x8
:: 4        5x12
:: 5        7x12
:: 6        8x12
:: 7        16x12
:: 8        12x16
:: 9        10x18


Sleep milliseconds
::do a wait or sleep in milliseconds. milliseconds should be greater than 0.


Locate row column
::locate the position of cursor in row and column specified (both 0 index based).
::if row is less than 0, is interpreted as 0.
::if row is greater than the max row (in the console screen buffer), is interpreted as the max row.
::if column is less than 0, is interpreted as 0.
::if column is greater than the max row (in the console screen buffer), is interpreted as the max row.


Print text
::print text without new line to end. The text can use oem escape sequences.
::please see the regular expressions in down.


Print color text ...
::print text in HEXADECIMAL color without new line to end. You can repeat arguments.
::the text recognize the next oem escape sequences:
\n print a newline
\\ print \
\Number  HEXADECIMAL ascii number code from 00 to FF.
Example: \01 is face character
Example: \41 is A
Note 2: You can repeat arguments.
Example: BG.exe Print A "Text in color A" B "Text in color B"


FCPrint row column [color text ...]
::begin printing of colored text in the row and col (zero index based). The column is fixed.
::row and column can be outside the console screen buffer limits.


Play soundfile.wav [ntimes]
::play soundfile.wav from begin to the end
::if ntimes is specified the play is repeated the number of times specified.
::(this function is different from the utility sound.exe where the second parameter correspond to seconds.)


::::: Colours :::::
[background]foreground
colours values is a one hexadecimal (0123456789ABCDEF) digit for each concept.


0 = Black
1 = Blue
2 = Green
3 = Aqua
4 = Red
5 = Purple
6 = Yellow
7 = White
8 = Gray
9 = Light Blue
A = Light Green
B = Light Aqua
C = Light Red
D = Light Purple
E = Light Yellow
F = Bright White
```